# Cast int to void in a 2D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

How safe would it be to do the following cast considering that the size of the pointer varies? (32/64 bits) Could it lead to incorrect program behavior?

```
#define APL 1
#define GRP 2

void *fruits[][2] = {
    {"Apples", (void *) APL},
    {"Grapes", (void *) GRP},
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> considering that the size of the pointer varies?

That plays no role, the standard allows casting integers to pointers.

But the result of the cast is (apart from a constant expression evaluating to 0) implementation-defined, and probably not a pointer to memory you are allowed to manipulate or even read.

> Could it lead to incorrect program behavior?

If you use these pointers (cast to other pointer types and dereference the result, for example), that can lead to undefined behaviour, and cause various sorts of bad behaviour.

Comment: So it is safe to do it as the example above. Now, when you say "cast to other pointer types" would that be something like: `void p*; int i = (int) p; p = (void *)i;`?

Comment: It's safe in the sense that the standard allows `(void*) 1`. It is not safe in the sense that you now have pointers in the array that are probably not null pointers, but don't point to valid memory. With "casting to other pointer types ...", I meant something along the lines of `int i = *(int*)p;`, where `p` is e.g. the result of `(void*)1`. That would - except in some very unlikely circumstances - be undefined behaviour, and frequently cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Got it. Would you recommend then to use `char *fruits[][2]` and convert the int value to a null-terminated string?

Comment: Not really, having `(type *) integer` is almost always a bad idea. The exceptions I know are 1. if `integer` is a constant expression with value 0, then you get a null pointer; 2. if `integer` is the address of a hardware register or something similar and there is no OS to mess with the address space. I'm not sure what your aim is, maybe using a `struct` would serve you better. It seems the first is the name of the fruit, and the second an integer encoding its type.

Comment: `typedef struct fruit_struct { char * name; int fruit_type; } fruit; fruit fruits[2] = {{"Apples", APL}, {"Grapes", GRP}};`

Comment: You are right, a struct would be the appropriate type to use. Thanks for all the info!